# Set vertical axis limits above/beneath the maximum/minimum resp. value

Tags: pgfplots

I would like to have my vertical axis 1.0 above the maximum value and 1.0 beneath the minimum value (implicit). Though that `enlarge y limits` would do the job, however it does not. I'm not sure how this function actually works and if it is the correct approach to solve my problem.

With my MWE, the vertical range is between 2 and 7, so I would like to have my vertical axis set between 1 and 8. Implicit of the plotted values; so  `ymin=1` and `ymax=8` is not an answer.

**Here's my MWE**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
    x,value
    0, 3
    5, 6
    14, 7
    31, 2
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \centering
    \begin{axis}[
    enlarge y limits = 1
    ]
    \addplot table [x=x, y=value, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `enlarge y limit={abs=1}`.

Comment: For a reference: chapter 4.14, page 273 (in the manual of the 2.xx version, which is the one I have on Ubuntu).

Comment: Thanks, it is clear to me. If no `abs` is specified, does it enlarge by pt's?

Comment: No, it will enlarge *relatively* to the computed range. 0.2 means 20% --- @Jake, what about writing an answer? ;-)

Comment: @Rmano: Would you mind writing one? You've added all that useful information, my comment was really just meant to get the OP back on track quickly while someone writes a proper answer explaining how the `enlarge y limits` key works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, as you can see in the manual (chapter 4.14, page 273, in the manual of the 2.xx version), you have a relative enlargement:

> ```
> /pgfplots/enlarge y limits=auto|true|false|upper|lower| val |value=val |abs value= val | abs= val |rel= val 
> (initially auto)
> ```

so your `enlarge y limits = 1` enlarge the limits of the y axes by 100%; probably you can obtain what you are looking for with a 10% enlargement like
`enlarge y limits = 0.1` or similar value.

To enlarge it by a fixed value you should do

```
enlarge y limits={abs=1}
```

to obtain:

[image: Output]